# Quick Sort algorithm implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Please find my quicksort implementation below in javascript.

```
const A = [4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3];

const partition = function(l, h) {
    
    let pivot = A[l];
    let i = l;
    let j = h;
    
    while(A[i] <= pivot) {
        i++;
    }
    
    while(A[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
    }
    
    if (i < j) {
        let temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }
    
    let temp1 = A[l];
    A[l] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp1;
    
    return j;
}

const quickSort = function (l, h) {
    if (l < h) {
        let piIdx = partition(l, h);
        console.log('the pidx is ', piIdx);
        quickSort(l, piIdx - 1);
        quickSort(piIdx + 1, h);
    }
}

quickSort(0, A.length - 1);

console.log('array after quicksort call ', A);
```

The output is as below:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 6, 4 ]
```

The last set of elements haven't been sorted properly. Could anyone please have a look and let me know the problem.

thanks

Comment: you can get a visualization here https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit

Comment: Obviously, your partitioning stops short. With your example, the pivot is 4 and i and j are 1 and h respectively. Then you put the pivot at index j. The way quicksort works, the pivot should now be in its correct place after sorting, but it isn't. You haven't looked at anything between the 6 and the 3, but you need to look at every element for partitioning. I think you should keep going after the first swap until i and j meet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `partition` function will at most perform 2 swaps. This cannot be right.

The process of swapping (the first one in your code) should be repeated until `i` has arrived at `j`.

Not the problem, but as the function is mutating `A`, that should be a parameter of the function -- that is best practice.

Here is an update of your function, with a test script below it that tests the implementation for 1000 arrays that are randomly shuffled:

```js
const partition = function(A, l, h) { // A is parameter
    let pivot = A[l];
    let i = l;
    let j = h;
    while (true) { // Keep going
        while(A[i] <= pivot) {
            i++;
        }        
        while(A[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }        
        if (i >= j) break; // All done
        let temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }
    A[l] = A[j];
    A[j] = pivot; // We already know A[l], no need for temp
    return j;
}

const quickSort = function (A, l, h) { // A is parameter
    if (l < h) {
        let piIdx = partition(A, l, h);
        quickSort(A, l, piIdx - 1);
        quickSort(A, piIdx + 1, h);
    }
}

// Test the implementation
function shuffle(a) {
    let i = a.length;
    while (i) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i--);
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
}

const A = [...Array(50).keys()]; // is sorted
const ref = A.toString(); // string to compare solution with
for (let attempt = 0; attempt < 1000; attempt++) {
    shuffle(A);
    quickSort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
    if (A.toString() != ref) {
        console.log('Error: array not sorted after quicksort call ', ...A);
        break;
    }
}
console.log("all tests done");
```

Answer (score -1):

You are halfway there ,
you are iterating the low and high but those both along with there swap needs to be in a loop that goes from low all the way to high
meaning until high does not overlap low , the loop will keep on going .
and once the loop breaks you got your index of putting the pivot
you also need to have a pivot index that will help you at the end to swap the j with the pivot index;
so it should be like this

```
var pivotIndex=l;
   while(i<j){
    while(A[i] <= pivot) {
        i++;
    }
    
    while(A[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
    }
    
    if (i < j) {
        let temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }
    
    let temp1 = A[l];
    A[l] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp1;
   }
    [nums[pivotIndex],nums[j]]=[nums[j],[nums[pivotIndex]]
    return j;}
```

I hope this help